# Camera Properties from Blender to generate Point Cloud

Tags: rotation, rendering, translation, blender, point-clouds

I used Blender to generate some color images and their corresponding depth map, along with their camera properties(intrinsic and extrinsic).

Then I want to use these information to generate a 3D point cloud from these 2D images using 2D to 3D projection techniques.

Here is the viewpoint of one the cameras in Blender. 
[image: viewpoint of one of the cameras in Blender]

I wanted to have the rotation and translation matrix of the camera.
I used the code in this link [camera matrix for Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38009/3x4-camera-matrix-from-blender-camera/38210) written by @rfabbri and I used this method "get_3x4_RT_matrix_from_blender" to have the rotation matrix.

After that I want to do 2D to 3D projection with all of these information.

For 2D to 3D projection, I wrote the following code in Java:

```
static double[] projUVZtoXY( double u, double v, double d) 
{
    // "u" and "v" are the pixel number of 2D image and 
    // "d" is the depth of this pixel (distance of the point to camera) 
    double[] p = new double[]{u, v, 1};     

    double[] translate = calibStruct.getM_Trans();         // Translation Matrix, from **T_world2cv** matrix in **get_3x4_RT_matrix_from_blender** method
    double[] rotation = calibStruct.getM_RotMatrix();      // Rotation Matrix, from **R_world2cv** matrix in **get_3x4_RT_matrix_from_blender** method
    double[] K = calibStruct.getM_K();                     // Intrinsic Matrix, from K matrix in **get_calibration_matrix_K_from_blender** method

    double[][] invertR = invert33(rotation);               // This method give me R^-1 matrix
    double[][] invertK = invert33(K);                      // This method give me K^-1 matrix

    double[][] invK_mul_depth = multiply33_scalar(invertK, d);         // this method multiply scalar value of "d" to "invertK" matrix
    double[] invK_mul_depth_p = multiply33_31(invK_mul_depth, p);      // this method multiply 3*3 matrix of "invK_mul_depth" by 3*1 matrix of "p"

    // subtract translation Matrix from the "invK_mul_depth_p" matrix
    double[] d_InvK_p_trans = new double[]{invK_mul_depth_p[0] - translate[0], 
                                            invK_mul_depth_p[1] - translate[1], 
                                            invK_mul_depth_p[2] - translate[2]};      

    double[] xyz = multiply33_31(invertR, d_InvK_p_trans );
    return xyz;
}
```

All the above code is trying to implement this 3D warping algorithm, to project uv pixel to XYZ 3D point.

[image: 2D to #d algorithm]

But when I generate the 3D point cloud, it looks like this: (in Meshlab)
[image: Point Cloud Demonstration in Meshlab]

It is the point cloud of just one image, the following image:
[image: Image used to generate point cloud]

I can't understand what happened here. And why in 3D point Cloud, all of the players in the image, are repeated in a line !

Could anyone guess what is happening?

I think maybe the Rotation Matrix that I get it from Blender, is not correct. What's your idea?

Thanks,

Mozhde

Comment: My first guess is the image from meshlab would look correct if you were looking at it from the camera location and not from above. Instead of a single point for an item you appear to have it repeat until the next object. So your creating points that are `>z-depth` when it needs to be `>z-depth and <z-depth+0.3`. This will lead to obscured parts being missing in the point cloud.

Comment: @sambler yes in Meshlab, it will look correct when I look at it from the camera location. But for the other datasets like Breakdancer and Ballet, when I create the point cloud from one of the images, their objects don't be repeated, even if I look at it from above in Meshlab. I think maybe it's related to Rotation Matrix. For example when I multiply it to a 3*3 matrix like `[1 0 0.. 0 -1 0.. 0 0 1 ]`, then items in point cloud repeated horizontally (in x axis), not like this (in y axis). I don't understand where I need to use >z-depth+0.3 ?

Comment: @rfabbri would you please look at my problem? I used your code to get rotation and translation matrix, and I think maybe the problem is from there. The `R_bcam2cv`  part.  I really need your help.